What causes Linux to be unable to share WiFi, while Windows can?
When I boot up Windows on my dual-boot laptop, it is trivially easy to share my WiFi connection with other device(s), by simply going to the hotspot settings and enabling the hotspot. This does not automatically turn off the WiFi receiver. However, whenever I reboot back to Ubuntu, I have tried several approaches, but whatever I tried, I can't get a hotspot to start up without it automatically disabling my WiFi receiver. Of course, without a cabled internet connection, this is completely pointless for all but the most specific purposes, where both my laptop and the connecting device would only need access to an internal network (but no access to the internet).
That's why I would like to know why Linux seems to be less capable of making use of the hotspot functionality than Windows seems to be, and I would like to ask for some advice on what I might be able to try to get a hotspot to work. Would I need to install some other software to more properly communicate with the WiFi chip? For example, I've followed https://www.baeldung.com/linux/setup-wifi-hotspot which seems to imply this should work on my laptop (iw list does show AP and AP/VLAN in there), but running the nmcli command listed there simply automatically turns off my WiFi.

Without listing any details of your "several approaches" or exact command lines that turn off your wifi, this would be hard to debug.

I've listed one of the approaches I used (and I also just tried the Ubuntu settings interface), but what information would you need to be able to help? I'm not sure listing 3 more approaches I've tried will help much in answering my question in general, but let me know if there's something you'd need.

It should be possible to create an extra interface on the same wifi card PHY with ip and then put an access point on with nmcli at least in theory.  It's creating that extra adapter instance that's not normally done in Linux that probably gives trouble.

It looks like it's actually iw dev <wlan0> interface add <wlan0if1> that you'd use to create the extra interface. I'm working from notes and don't have time to build and test a real answer.

sorry, I don't think I'm following. What do you mean by the command you gave? Would I need to fill in something for <wlan0> and <wlan0if1>? I can't find much details about this based on what you mentioned here.

It's quite standard to use </> around something you have to fill in, and that is also what @davolfman means here, as you haven't told us what your wifi card's device name is we can't even tell you what those should be.

Basically, you have described your problem only in broad generalities and have not included any details of what you actually tried, including exact commands you ran (other than iw list) and their outputs (which you didn't show at all)...  So we are left guessing.
